# Why after refreshing the page my items gets changed?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, angular2-services

My code:

.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="secondary">
    <ion-title>Reviews</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addReview()">
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let review of reviews">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img src="https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/{{review.title}}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{review.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{review.description}}</p>
        <ion-icon *ngIf="review.rating < 50" danger name="sad"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon *ngIf="review.rating >= 50" secondary name="happy"></ion-icon>
        {{review.rating}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Reviews } from '../../providers/reviews';
import { AddReviewPage } from '../add-review-page/add-review-page';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  reviews: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public reviewService: Reviews, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.reviewService.getReviews().then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.reviews = data;
    });

  }

  addReview() {

    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddReviewPage);
    modal.onDidDismiss(review => {
      if (review) {
        this.reviews.push(review);
      //  console.log('inside modal',review);
        this.reviewService.createReviews(review);
      }
    });
    modal.present();

  }



}
```

.providers

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the Reviews provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class Reviews {

  data: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello Reviews Provider');
    this.data = null;
  }

  getReviews() {
    if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/reviews').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        resolve(this.data);
      });
    });
  }

  createReviews(review){
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/reviews',JSON.stringify(review)).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log('inside create review', res.json());
    })

  }
}
```

When I am adding data, items are added successfully  with different avatars.But when I am refreshing the page the items are removed and the avatars gets changed.Why is it so?
screenshots are provided below.

[image: Adding reviews]

[image: after refresing the page]

[image: this is how the db is looking with the values.]

Comment: Looks like it's a problem in your '../../providers/reviews';.
In that provider you save them permanent normally to an API or localStorage.
Can you show the code from that provider?

Comment: @Hendrik Driesen, I have updated the code.

Comment: What does `createReviews(review)` do?

Comment: it will add the new review in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Is the data you added correctly in your database in your backend and do you get the correct data in your console.log(data) in ionViewDidLoad()? If you get the correct data there try to change the promise to an ionic2 event. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

The reason that you lose your data after a refresh is that before you refresh your page, every review is also saved in the local variable reviews: any;. So he does not need to get it from the backend.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot of the database.And locally only object with the id is stored.Is it wrong?

Comment: actually, I found on querying in the database, my data is only not populated correctly.Can you help me out with this?

Comment: I don't know a lot about databases. What system of DB do you use, is it MongoDB? Maybe its easiest to open a new question specifically about your database problem. Does your back-end receive the correct data before you write it down to your database? If it's node based, just use console.log() to check the incoming request.

Comment: I am using mongdb..shall I update the code? If you can help?

Comment: I can always look at it, but I haven't yet worked with mongoDB.